# jupyter notebook behind nginx unable to save

Tags: nginx, jupyter-notebook

I have a machine running a `jupyter notebook` with the following settings:

```
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 9999
c.NotebookApp.base_url = '/notebook/'
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.NotebookApp.trust_xheaders = True
```

and an `nginx` conf set up like this:

```
server {
listen   80;


server_name example.domain.com;

return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 default_server ssl;
    server_name         example.domain.com;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    ssl_certificate     chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key .key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    location /notebook {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/notebook;
        proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";   
    }    

    location /notebook/nbextensions {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/notebook/nbextensions/;

        proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # to configure the kernel for python
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";    
    }
}
```

The idea is that I have a different service running on 8081, and I want to be able to access the notebooks on example.domain.com/notebook.

Using the notebook directly on the local machine on localhost:9999 works absolutely fine. But when I try to access it from remote address everything works, except it cannot save the notebook.

This is the (somewhat edited) error message:

```
[W 11:02:37.568 NotebookApp] Unexpected error while saving file: notebook.ipynb [|
Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.ipynb_checkpoints/notebook-checkpoint.ipynb'|
[E 11:02:37.569 NotebookApp] {                                                                                                        |
      "Content-Type": "application/json",                                                                                             |
      "Connection": "upgrade",                                                                                                        |
      "Content-Length": "4600",                                                                                                       |
      "X-Real_ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",                                                                                                 |
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|f9bfac9e|92b9bb14e19945238a1b3445e08c86f7|1484213065",                                                        |
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|f9bfac9e|92b9bb14e19945238a1b3445e08c86f7|1484213065; username-example-domain-com=\"2|1:0|10:1484213084|27:us|
ername-example-domain-com|44:Mjk3MDYzYWU2M2FkNGVmNDlkZWFiMGY4NjU5NDZlOTU=|8b4ceb3a6ebd248a84beeffd867815c7269a98f2ba1a360562034ca21c95|
ae9a\"",                                                                                                                              |
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",                                                                                         |
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0",                                   |
      "X-Nginx-Proxy": "true",                                                                                                        |
      "Referer": "https://example.domain.com/notebook/notebooks/notebook.ipynb", |
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",                                                                                            |
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",                                                                     |
      "Host": "example.domain.com",                                                                                                   |
      "X-Forwarded-For": "157.181.241.173",                                                                                           |
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"                                                                                            |
    }
[E 11:02:37.569 NotebookApp] 500 PUT /notebook/api/contents/notebook.ipynb (127.0
.0.1) 169.93ms referer=https://example.domain.com/notebook/notebooks/notebook.ipynb
```

The very same thing works, if I do it from the localhost. I've tried various other setups of the nginx confs I found on the internet, but couldn't find any. I am running the notebook under my own user, but my user has write access to said folder (and also the notebook, as running it on localhost does not show this issue). As far as I know nginx should not change the running user at it has nothing to do with that, it is just proxying calls to the jupyter notebook server. So I have no idea what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder `.ipynb_checkpoints` did not have the correct permissions, so they had to be set manually: see the issue on [github](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/124) for more details..